# Existing Algorithm for Scheduling Problems?

Tags: java, algorithm, constraints, linear-programming

Let's say I want to build a function that would properly schedule three bus drivers to drive in a week with the following constraints:

- Each driver must not drive more than five times per week
- There must be two drivers driving everyday
- They will rest one day each week (will not clash with other drivers' rest day)

What kind of algorithm would be used to solve a problem like this?

I looked through several sites and I found these:

```
1) Backtracking algorithm (brute force)
2) Genetic algorithm
3) Constraint programming
```

Frankly, these are all "culture shock" for me as I have never learnt any kind of linear programming in the past. There are two things I want to know:

1) Which algorithm will best suit the case scenario above?

2) What would be the simplest algorithm to solve this problem?

3) Please suggest any other algorithms I can look into to solve the above problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the third constraint. Doesn't the fact that each driver does not drive more than five days imply that they rest at least two days a week? The fact that there must be two drivers every day implies that at most one can rest on a given day. The third constraint seems redundant here.

Comment: sometimes redundant constraints are desirable to reduce the possible solution set faster.

Comment: Do you want solve the problem to optimality or is a near optimal (heuristically optained solution) sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is a discrete optimization problem, so linear programming is probably not a good idea (since it is meant for continuous optimization). You can still solve this using linear programming (it will become an integer or mixed-integer program) but that is exponentially heard (if your input size is small then it is ok).

Now back to the comparison:

1. Brute force : worst.
2. Genetic: Can not guarantee optimality. The algorithm may not be able to solve the problem.
3. Constraint programming: definitely the best in this case (and in many discrete optimization problems). There is a super efficient implementation of it in IBM ILOG CPLEX solver (but is is not free, it is free for academia or for testing though).

Comment: Can any of them be implemented under two hours?

Comment: implementing the general case is hard, but all of them can be implemented under 2 hours for you particular problem.

Comment: I cannot agree with the statement that constraint programming (CP) would be better than mixed integer programming (MIP) in this case. All algorithm you talked about are exponentially hard, including CP, and CP implementations are usually less efficient than MIP, in particular the CPLEX one. All real-world scheduling problems are solved with MIP these days, even the most complex ones (with complex decomposition algorithm, but still the 'core' is a MIP), and IMHO MIP is clearly the way to go here. Granted, it is harder to implement from scratch (!), you need to use one of the...

Comment: ...efficient implementation out there. But if the size of the problem is reasonable, a free implementation such as GLPK or COIN-OR will do just fine. Besides, you can use a modelling language (see the GLPK manual), so you basically just have to write your constraints in a text file and run an external program on this. Now, if this is some kind of homework and you have to program an algorithm yourself, things are different. Finally, implementing an efficient CP algorithm in two hours sounds very optimistic, at best (even for a particular problem).

Comment: Yes, I agree my comparison with MIP with CP is not right. CP is indeed exponentially hard. Let me revise my answer, if you use one of the solvers then either MIP or CP is fine, but if you want to implement the algorithm, i think, CP will be a easier algorithm to implement. My original answer still holds for the original 3 options though, CP is better than brute force and genetic.

Answer (score 3):

1) I agree brute force is bad.

2) Your Problem is an Integer Problem. They can be solved with Linear Programming though.

3) You can distinquish 2 different approaches: heuristics and exact approaches. 
Heuristics provide good solutions in reasonable computation time. They are used when there are strict requirements on the computation time or if the problem is too hard to calculate an optimal solution. Genetic Algorithms is a heuristic.

As your Problem is comparably simple, you would probably go with an exact approach.

4) The standard way to solve this exacly, is to embed a Linear Program in a Branch & Bound search tree. There is lots of literature on it. The procedure can be outlined as follows:

1. Solve the Linear Program with the Simplex-Algorithm
2. Find a fractional variable for branching. I.e. x=1.5
3. Create two new nodes and add the constraints x<=1 and x>=2 respectively
4. Go into one node (selected by some strategy)
5. Go to point 1

Additionally, at every node in the tree, after point 1, the algorithms checks, if a node can  be pruned. That means to stop searching 'deeper' from this node on, because

a) the problem has become infeasible,

b) a better solution already exists,

c) an integer solution is found. This objective value of this solution is used to determine point b.

The procedure finishes when all nodes are pruned.

Luckily, as Nicolas stated, there are free implementations that do just this. All you have to do is to create your model. Code its objective and constraints in some tool and let it solve.